# Dynamically change text color with jquery and ajax, with different colors, different text and having same attribute/class

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I made table structure with dynamically data on view, but I want to add different color on different payment status and they have same class on each payment status, but when i click on page 1 or 2 or 3 its show only on single page not on every page.I want to show it to all pages.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.paginate_button a').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "",
      method: "POST",
      data: $("#DataTables_Table_0 td .custom-text-badge"),
      success: function(data) {
        $("#DataTables_Table_0 td .custom-text-badge:contains('Success')").css({
          "color": "red"
        });
        $("#DataTables_Table_0 td .custom-text-badge:contains('pending')").css({
          "color": "green"
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[this is image link for payment success and pending text color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10meL.png)

[this image link for pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C06Yy.png)

[this image link when click on another page link 2/3 ect no color shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyni7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a class with that properties:

```
.red{
  color: red,
 }
```

When you want to add your custom formatting on a row, add that class insted of formatting the CSS directly in that callback.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.paginate_button a').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "",
      method: "POST",
      data: $("#DataTables_Table_0 td .custom-text-badge"),
      success: function(data) {
        $("#DataTables_Table_0 td .custom-text-badge:contains('Success')").addClass("red");
        $("#DataTables_Table_0 td .custom-text-badge:contains('pending')").addClass("red");
      }
    });
  });
});
```